# Problems with Java/Kotlin Build Application using IDEA

Tags: java, windows, kotlin, build, jar

I can't build my Kotlin application. I've tried a lot of things and still failed. Farthest error I got was:

```
no main manifest attribute, in file.jar
```

manifest.mf in jar is always the same:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.dolta.MainKt
```

I've tried building using gradle and using IDEA

using IDEA:

[Inside the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2aSu.png)

[Inside META-INF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK9gs.png)

using Gradle:

[Inside the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcx4b.png)